# Copying data into a SQL Server central DB from many databases via web services ...regularly

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have **MANY SUB-OFFICES** each one with its own independent and isolated SQL Server database. I have been tasked to design a new **CENTRAL OFFICE** Database so that we can upload "constantly" data from the sub offices. The central office database does not exist so I'm free to design it from scratch.

I mainly need to **COPY CERTAIN TABLES** from **EACH** sub office instance to a NEW database on the central office, and this will happen regularly.

The transfer will occur via web services (therefore XML) since each DB is stored on a different location so that creates the following constraints:

- a) Data arrives in chunks (I can still control what data comes first)
- b) MainOffice DB will NOT have direct access to any sub office database
- c) Each sub office might decide to run the update at different times.

I'm planning to add an `OfficeCode` column on certain tables on the central database so we can store the sub office code, that way I will be able to know what record belong to what sub office.

**MY QUESTION:**
What is the recommended way to handle the fact that PK values on the SubOffice DB will not be the same as the PK values on the central office and therefore the FK possibly will end up pointing to the wrong records, after being imported?

As I mentioned, data will arrive in chunks via web services and not the entire set of tables at once, but I can control what to do with the data arrived since I write the web service itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should seriously consider using UNIQUEIDENTIFIER values for the keys.  Otherwise, study up on the ways to deal with replication issues when using int values for keys.

Comment: Hi John, that's the easy answer I know, but I kind of feel there must be a more optimized solution. This DB will be only used for REPORTS ...so that's another thing to keep in consideration

Answer (score 2):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, why not use the off-the-shelf solution?

SQL Server replication already covers everything you described and has explicit support for [Replicating Identity Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152543.aspx):

> To use identity columns in a replication topology that has updates at
>   more than one node, each node in the replication topology must use a
>   different range of identity values, so that duplicates do not occur.
>
> For example, the Publisher could be assigned the range 1-100,
>   Subscriber A the range 101-200, and Subscriber B the range 201-300. If
>   a row is inserted at the Publisher and the identity value is, for
>   example, 65, that value is replicated to each Subscriber. When
>   replication inserts data at each Subscriber, it does not increment the
>   identity column value in the Subscriber table; instead, the literal
>   value 65 is inserted. Only user inserts, but not replication agent
>   inserts cause the identity column value to be incremented.
>
> Replication handles identity columns across all publication and
>   subscription types, allowing you to manage the columns manually or
>   have replication manage them automatically.

When you signed up to rewrite replication from scratch over web services you signed up to redo +15 years of know-how and experience in replicating data that SQL Server replication has already solved. This problem you see now is just one of the many many problems that lay ahead. I reckon There are legitimate cases to use another technology instead of replication, are you sure your case is one of them?

Comment: Can this solution be used on the Central Database when the data is NOT coming from the Input DB directly ..but instead from a C# written Web Service that receives the data inside an XML file? Again, the Database are NOT connected so direct replication is simply NOT an option